# How can we get the number of all possible non-negative integers similar to a given non-negative integer by re-arranging it using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Given a non-negative number say 1213, it should return 12 because there are 12 possible integers similar to 1213 i.e., 1123,1132,1213,1231,1312,1321,2113,2131,2311,312,3121 and 3211. Same with 10, it should return 1 and 12 should return 2 and if the number is 120 it should return 4 as combinations are 120,102,210,201.

Comment: what means similar?

Comment: You need to compute permutations without repetitions. This is more of mathematical question than programming

Comment: @NinaScholz I think she meant permutations.

Comment: like this.. if the given number is 1213 then the possible combinations are 1123,1132,1213,1231,1312,1321,2113,2131,2311,312,3121 and 3211. if the number is 120 then combination should be 120,102,210,201 @NinaScholz

Comment: you could add this information to the question.

Comment: Done @NinaScholz can you solve this now using javascript?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this formula to get the total number of unique permutations excluding permutations with leading zero.

Lets define some symbols:

```
n = Total Number of digits 
z = Number of zeros
r1, r2, ..., rn  = repetition count of digits with count > 1
fact(p) = factorial of number of p

Total permutations = (n - z) * fact(n - 1) / fact(r1) * fact(r2) * .... * fact(rn)

For example, for 1213,
n = 4, z = 0, r1 (digit 1) = 2
permutations = (4 - 0) * fact(4 - 1) / fact(2) = 4 * 6 / 2 = 12
```

You can easily convert this to program.

```js
    function factorial(n) {
      if (n <=1)
        return 1;
      return n * factorial(n-1);
    }
    
    function getPermutations(number) {
      var n = number.toString().split('').length;
      var r = {};
      number.toString().split('').forEach(function(digit){
          r[digit] = r[digit] || 0;
          r[digit] += 1;
      });
      
      var z = number.toString().split('').reduce(function(count, digit) {
        return (digit === '0') ? count + 1 : count;
      }, 0);
      
      var denominator = Object.keys(r).map(function (key) { return r[key]; }).reduce(function(result, curr) {
        return result * factorial(curr);
      }, 1);
      
      //console.log(n, r, z);
      return (n - z) * factorial(n - 1) / denominator;
    
    }
    
    var result = getPermutations(1216);
    console.log(result);
```

**Note :** This is basic implementation and would not be the most optimum. Also, factorial calculation involves large numbers and would probably fail for large inputs.

Comment: Can you explain how did you come up with `(n - z) * fact(n - 1)` ?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for an **anagram algorithm** :

This script find every anagram of a string then delete every number starting with zero :

```
var allAnagrams = function(arr) {
var anagrams = {};
arr.forEach(function(str) {
    var recurse = function(ana, str) {
        if (str === '') 
            anagrams[ana] = 1;
        for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
            recurse(ana + str[i], str.slice(0, i) + str.slice(i + 1));
    };
    recurse('', str);
});
return Object.keys(anagrams);
}

var arr = ['120']; //declare your number
var anag = allAnagrams(arr); //send it to the function


for (var i in anag) {  //delete leading 0
if((anag[i].charAt(0)) === '0' ) {
 anag.splice(i);
}
}

console.log(anag); //print array
console.log(anag.length); // print length
```

Here the output will be :

```
["102", "120", "201", "210"]
4
```

Comment: But this also includes the case where anagram has a leading zero, which OP does not want in results. For example 10, your program will return 2, but it should be 1 according to OP's requirement

Comment: Thanks, I did not really understood OP too.. I just edited my JS, leading zero are now deleted from the array.